# Error while using colors in latex table?

Tags: tables, color

I am working on color table and using code below.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{framed,color}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{parskip}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{1,0.8,0.3}
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{0.9}
\definecolor{yellow}{rgb}{1,0.5,0}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\usepackage{Sweave}
\begin{document}






\leavevmode 
\newline 
\leavevmode 
\newline 
\begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=10pt,leftmargin=1, rightmargin=1, linecolor=orange,outerlinewidth=1, innerleftmargin=15, innertopmargin=15,innerbottommargin=15] 
\textbf{Detailed Genotype Table} 
\centering 
\rowcolors{1}{}{yellow}
\begin{tabular}{>{\rule{0pt}{.5cm}}c >{\arraybackslash}m{2cm}>{\arraybackslash}m{2cm}>{\arraybackslash}m{6cm} >{\arraybackslash}m{3cm}} 
\hline 
\rowcolor{orange} \textbf{data} &\textbf{dummy} &\textbf{value} &\textbf{rough} &\textbf{text}\\ 
\hline 
rsxx  & CreT  & 17603472, 19141561  & twet  & 17603472, 19141561\\ 
rs7193xx343  & TrT  & 19597491, 21760908  & twer  & 19597491, 21760908\\ 
rxx376333  & CCe  & 2017r3747  & twertw  & 20173747\\ 
\hline 
\leavevmode 
\newline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{mdframed} 
\leavevmode 
\newline 

\leavevmode 
\newline 
\end{document}
```

There is no colored table? May i know where i am wrong?

[image]

Comment: I can't be sure if this is a solution since I have not installed the `mdframed` and `sweave` packages, but the definition of `lightgray` should be `\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}`. Also, the definition of `yellow` in this example gives actually an orange color.

Comment: @manish: When posting an example like this, you should make sure that it's *minimal*, i.e. that it does not contain packages or code unrelated to the problem. In this case, the `mdframed` and `sweave` packages (and `parskip`, `comment`, `wrapfig` and a few others) have nothing to do with the table.

Comment: This question is very low quality. Your code is not minimal, and doesn't compile. Please read [ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: Just to inform, my above code is part of my complete latex report. I am not aware of which package clash with which one? Regards

Comment: An answer is not the appropriate place to post an edit to your question. Instead, please edit your original question to add additional information or clarification.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You loaded a lot of packages for your MWE, a lot of which were unnecessary, and a few of which clashed.

The most important package you need to load for a coloured table is the `colortbl` package.

It was quite hard to tell what you wanted, but here's a stripped-down version of your code that does colour some of the rows. If it's not what you want, please clarify your question.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{colortbl}

% new colours
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{1,0.8,0.3}
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\definecolor{yellow}{rgb}{1,0.5,0}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=10pt,leftmargin=1, rightmargin=1, linecolor=orange,outerlinewidth=1, innerleftmargin=15, innertopmargin=15,innerbottommargin=15] 
\textbf{Detailed Genotype Table} 
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{>{\rule{0pt}{.5cm}}c >{\arraybackslash}m{2cm}>{\arraybackslash}m{2cm}>{\arraybackslash}m{6cm} >{\arraybackslash}m{3cm}} 
\hline 
\rowcolor{orange}   \textbf{data} &\textbf{dummy} &\textbf{value} &\textbf{rough} &\textbf{text}\\ 
\hline 
\rowcolor{lightgray}        rsxx  & CreT  & 17603472, 19141561  & twet  & 17603472, 19141561\\ 
                     rs7193xx343  & TrT  & 19597491, 21760908  & twer  & 19597491, 21760908\\ 
                       rxx376333  & CCe  & 2017r3747  & twertw  & 20173747\\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{mdframed} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Above example works fine. But i need to make alternate rows colored in table. How can i implement it? I am using \rowcolors{1}{}{yellow}.

Comment: @manish: Since the alternating colours aren't part of this question (and you asked a new one about that), you should consider this question answered and mark it as such by clicking the check mark next to the answer.

Comment: Ok, i have already marked it as checked which means already answered But pls reply answer to my previous another question.